# Where to write Custom Helpers in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4, helper

I want to have a little string converter (translator) helper method. For example, I want to pass my string from the controller and get the result, so I don't want to repeatedly write the same helper function into the controller.

So that I can maybe use it like:

```
$oldStr = '12 Mayıs 2014';  // which means 12 May in English
$englishStr = custom_date_translator($oldStr);
```

and it does it's thing on the helper method.

Is the Service Providers for this purpose? It'd be good to learn the right way to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a custom `helpers.php`  file and setup Composer so that it's autoloaded.

For example, if you create the `helpers.php`  file in the `app/` directory, you could edit your `composer.json`  file to something like this :

```
 "autoload": {
     "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }, 
    "files": [
        "app/helpers.php"
    ]
},
```

Make sure to run `composer dump-autoload`  in your console to update the autoloader.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tip! I needed to open `<?php` tag without closing it and place `function xx() { }` and worked! Cheers!

Comment: Maybe a small hint, i always use if(!function_exists('myFunc')) to make sure its unique :)

Comment: @DonnyvanV Brilliant! Cheers guys!

Comment: Why do people keep adding functions to the global namespace!! -- always assume conflicts --